# How to remove index.php in a codeigniter site to help seo

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo

I want remove "index.php" from my url

```
http://localhost/simpleblog/index.php/blogger/NewBlogs
```

I need it as

```
http://localhost/simpleblog/blogger/NewBlogs
```

here shows my Controller Code

```
class Blogger extends CI_Controller {

    public function NewBlogs()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->layout="Yes"; //<-- add this*/
       /* $this->load->view('welcome_message');*/
        $this->load->view('Pages/SecondPage');
    }
}
```

Default Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->layout="Yes"; //<-- add this*/
   /* $this->load->view('welcome_message');*/
    $this->load->view('Pages/MainPage');
}
```

How to remove index.php ?

Comment: Try [reading the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: Deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]   is it correct

Answer (score 1):

### Removing the index.php file

By default, the `index.php` file will be included in your URLs:

```
example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
```

You can easily remove this file by using a `.htaccess`file with some simple rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

See [Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: I added the code as you have given and typed like this (  http://localhost/simpleblog/Blogger/NewBlogs  ) ..the error was  (Not Found

The requested URL /simpleblog/Blogger/NewBlogs was not found on this server.)

Comment: I added the code as you have given and typed like this (  http://localhost/simpleblog/Blogger/NewBlogs  ) ..the error was  (Not Found

The requested URL /simpleblog/Blogger/NewBlogs was not found on this server.)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enter this code in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And
  replace this code in config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

           To

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the index.php file

- First, go to  /application/config/config.php find

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

replace with

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

- Second, just create a .htaccess file at the root directory of your project

i.e `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

save your file with name `.htaccess`